# Connect device to local Tomcat

Tags: java, android, tomcat

I have started tomcat server on my local machine and on my machine I am able to access it via IP address i.e IPAddress:8080

Now i want to connect from smartphone browser to this tomcat. For example my Pc have ip:`192.168.1.140` and my device:`192.168.1.3` (same network).
So in browser device i try: `http://192.168.1.140:8080/myservices`, but not work.
On my router i have disabled the firewall but still not work. I can ping device from the Tomcat server.

any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have another computer, try pinging the server. Also try telnet  8080. I am guessing the second command would fail. If that's the case, your firewall (on the server) is blocking the incoming port 8080. Open it and you should be good to go.

Comment: if i try from another computer ping 192.168.1.140 it works..nut the command for telnet is?

Answer (score 0):

What OS are you using?

On Windows you might need to configure the firewall to allow incoming connections.